# Get total distance travelled using GPS doesn't update my location

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

Hi I'm currently learning about the GPS for development in Android. Now I've read about the basics through vogellas blog [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html). Now I already get the latitude and longitude and displayed it on my device but I don't know why it doesn't update my location even though I already set a runnable thread to fetch location every 3 seconds. Same reason why I can't check if I got the correct formula to get the total distance I've travelled.

This is my first time working with this so maybe someone can give me a tip or idea on how to.

I created a repository in github maybe someone can help me with this. See file [here](https://github.com/kahelnadiablo/distance_tracker) :)

EDIT:
Okay the main problem is that the onChangeLocation() seems doesn't work on my end. What I tried is to create a runnable to display the location every 3 seconds but it doesn't return the result I expected.

Did I missed out on something here?

Here's my code so far for easier viewing:

Main.java

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/*created by Kahel 08/16/2013
* to read more about the location manager go here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html
*
* */

public class Main extends Activity implements LocationListener {

    private TextView latitude, longitude, distance;
    private Button getLocation;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String provider;

    double distance_travelled;
    double latitude_prev;
    double longitude_prev;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        latitude = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_latitude);
        longitude = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_longitude);
        distance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_distance);
        getLocation = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_getLocation);

        checkGps();

        getCurrentLocation();

        getLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                locatorRunner();
            }
        });

    }

    private void locatorRunner(){
        Thread thread = new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while(true) {
                        sleep(3000);

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                 /*needs UI Thread*/
                                getCurrentLocation();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        thread.start();
    }

    private void getCurrentLocation(){
        // Get the location manager
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // Define the criteria how to select the locatioin provider -> use
        // default
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        Toast.makeText(Main.this,String.valueOf(location),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        //locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,1000L,500.0f, (LocationListener) location);


        // Initialize the location fields
        if (location != null) {
            System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
            onLocationChanged(location);
        } else {
            latitude.setText("Location not available");
            longitude.setText("Location not available");
            distance.setText("0");
        }
    }

    private void checkGps(){
        LocationManager service = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean enabled = service.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        Toast.makeText(Main.this,String.valueOf(enabled),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // Check if enabled and if not send user to the GSP settings
        // Better solution would be to display a dialog and suggesting to
        // go to the settings
        if (!enabled) {
            showGpsSettingDialog();
        }
    }

    private void showGpsSettingDialog(){
        /*Create a dialog to tell user to enable his GPS settings to pinpoint his or her location*/
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this);
        alertDialog.setTitle("Settings para sa lokasyon"); /*should be on a string values*/

        alertDialog
                .setMessage("Kasalukuyang hindi aktibo ang iyong GPS para makuha ang iyong lokasyon. Nais mo bang i-set ito ngayon?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Oo", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Hindi", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.cancel();
                    }
                });

        AlertDialog gpsSettingsDialog = alertDialog.create();
        gpsSettingsDialog.show();

    }

    /* Request updates at startup */
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
    }

    /* Remove the locationlistener updates when Activity is paused */
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        getLocation(location);
    }

    private void getLocation(Location location){

        int R = 6371;

        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        double lon = location.getLongitude();

        latitude_prev = lat;
        longitude_prev = lon;

        Double dlat = latitude_prev - lat;
        Double dlon = longitude_prev - lon;

        double a = Math.sin(dlat / 2) * Math.sin(dlat / 2) + Math.cos(latitude_prev) *
                Math.cos(lat) * Math.sin(dlon / 2) * Math.sin(dlon / 2);
        double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));

        distance_travelled =  R * c;

        latitude.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
        longitude.setText(String.valueOf(lon));
        distance.setText(String.valueOf(distance_travelled));
    }

    /*private double toRad(double d) {
        return d * Math.PI / 180;
    }*/

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:text="Latitude: "
                android:textSize="20dip" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_latitude"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="unknown"
                android:textSize="20dip" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView03"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:text="Longitute: "
                android:textSize="20dip" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_longitude"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="unknown"
                android:textSize="20dip" >
        </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Distance Travelled:"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="unknown"
                android:id="@+id/txt_distance"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Get Location"
            android:id="@+id/btn_getLocation"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.geolocation"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION " />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.geolocation.Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Note:

I added the button Start Tracking because I'm not sure if the onLocationChanged is working or not. hahaha!

Comment: It seems that getting location updates works using callbacks. Maybe this will help you: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#Updates

Comment: Hi @RobertM. Thanks for the comment and yup, I also think about that part which is why I tried to do a callback and request location every 3 seconds but it seems nothing really happens on my end. LocationListener is aready extended on my Activity I also tried that one already. See the java code from my repository. :)

Answer (score 1):

Basic approach for distance:

```
public class test extends Activity implements LocationListener{
   private LocationManager lm;
   private Location last;
   private long distance;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,1000,1,this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        lm.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if(last != null){
            distance += location.distanceTo(last);
        }

        last = new Location(location);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, this part is already implemented on my code but it doesn't seems to work. Please see my code in github by clicking the link above. :) Thanks!

Comment: @KaHeL Update the question to explain what is not working. Tell us the steps you take, the expected output, and what really happens.

Comment: What is now working is the part where it is supposed to get the location onLocationChanged. Will update the question about the steps in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement `LocationListener` to get current `GPS` location something like this :
**Set user permission firlst**

**Now get GPS location like this :**

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) 
getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

LocationListener locationListener = new MyLocationListener();  
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(  
LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

/*----------Listener class to get coordinates ------------- */
private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        //Get your location here
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but I already know about this part. What I want to know is how I can get the location from time to time. Please see my code in github. I posted the link above. I would appreciate it if you help me with it.

Comment: Why you are running thread to get update??
Just create a LocationManager and request location update with min time and min distance you want and it will autometically send you update on onLocationChanged method.
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, /*MIN TIME TO GET UPDATE*/, /*MIN DISTANE TO GET UPDATE*/, this);

Comment: Because I don't know if the onLocationChanged is Working properly. :) Will update the question and post the code here instead for easier viewing.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `getCurrentLocation()` every 3 second but this will not trigger `getLocation(location);`.

**getLocation(location);** will be called only when Location gets updated

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    getLocation(location);
}
```

Comment: There might be many reason, but here are few.
No update received from GPS, No updates from Service Provider.
Try testing while moving in open space like road/park and see the result.

Comment: hi, I conducted some test on my app using 2 mobile phones with hardcoded latitude and longitude on my code and tested it by connecting to a network. Now the total distance is computed with my mobile phone (LG Optimus Black GingerBread 2.3.3) but on the other hand my Galaxy Tab (7.0 Jellybean 4.1.2) doesnt get the current location. Meaning it doesn't get the total distance traveled. I wonder what went wrong with my code in here?

Comment: Your code is fine. GPS takes time to lock the location, technically [TTFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_first_fix)

Comment: In case of my Tab, it takes a seriously "lot" of time. hahaha! And in case of pinpointing the location using the network provider (they call it triangular method or something) it's also not working on both my phone. Eventhough I think I already set the permissions needed. maybe you have some idea about it?